# How to load input elements by the load function ? jquery

Tags: jquery

here is my code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".checkbox").change(function(){
            alert("test")
        });

        $(".loadInto").load("test.php");
    }
</script>

<td id="loadInto" > </td>
```

test.php script return this code :

```
<input type="checkbox" class='checkbox'/>
```

I succeed to load the input checkbox but when I press on the checkbox, I didn't get alert. why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) at this context, since you are loading the elements at run time.

```
$('#loadInto').on('change', ".checkbox", function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

Note : In your code `loadInto` is an `id` not a `class`. Keep an eye on that.

So change your selector `$("#loadInto").load("test.php");`